# rough bump texture when loading OBJ in three.js

Tags: three.js, textures, bump-mapping

We are having difficulties loading model in three.js

we are using OBJLoader2 because it smooths mesh properly, but somehow textures are looking way more rough then they should be.

some normal map issues:
[three.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfNbE.jpg)

and this is the render how it should look like (with different texture)
[rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzlNP.jpg)

Comment: An excerpt of the code would help understanding your situation better, maybe you can add the initialization of the materials in question? did you set the `normalScale` property of the material?

Comment: Also, how was the second image rendered? Is that three.js as well?

Comment: Crossposting: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/webgl-normal-map-issue/2531

Comment: Have you tried changing normalScale or bumpScale on your material?

Comment: there is no native support of the three.js when u load the model and using MTL. its bumpMap by default. But it should be normalMap. So if you load normalMaps manually and apply it it starts to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When u load the model and using MTL its bumpMap by default. But it should be normalMap. So if you load normalMaps manually and apply it it starts to work.